# error while using session state sql server mode

Tags: asp.net

I got this error while using sql server mode is session state

Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server. Please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above.

and one more thing to use this mode do i need to install iis on my pc..??

need help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the relevant tables and sprocs in your database using the [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: all the tables are ready ...but i constantly getting this error. i have two tables in my server 
ASPStateTempApplications and 
ASPStateTempSessions

what should i do?

Comment: Give this a try: "Go to aspstate database > click properties > permission > add (public) database role > permission to this role" (http://forums.asp.net/t/969708.aspx/1)

Comment: that is also done..but some problem there or what i can only add execution role for the public. and if i add any other role than it gives error.